# Stored procedure to select column from table and insert to multiple table in mysql

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures, create-table

I want to select values from `basic2` and insert into `basic3` and `basic4` using stored procedure.

These are the table definitions:

```
create table basic2(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table basic3(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

create table basic4(
    id int AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

this is the `new_person` store procedure

```
drop procedure if exists new_person;
DELIMITER // 
CREATE PROCEDURE new_person 
    select (id, name,address)
    from basic2;
    BEGIN

        START TRANSACTION;
        INSERT INTO basic3 (id,name,address) 
                VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),bname,baddress);

        INSERT INTO basic4 (id,name,address) 
                VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID(),bname,baddress); 

        COMMIT;
    END//

    DELIMITER;
```

Comment: please provide which is your output now! and what is the desired one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do it by two way one for using cursor and another is using SELECT with insert i thing for you SELECT is better

Like this

INSERT INTO basic3 (name,address) 
SELECT name, address FROM basic2;